# linux c socket error: Input/output error

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I've got a "Input/output error" error when I try to send data to a tcp server. What does this mean in terms of sockets? Its basically the same code I was used always worked fine. I was hoping someone could tell me what are the reasons of inpput/output error when I tried to send over a socket and how I could check/fix them. Any help is appreciated.

```
struct SOCKETSTUS {
int sendSockFd;
int recvSockFd;
short status;
long heartBeatSendTime;
long heartBeatRecTime;
long loginPackSendTime;
};

struct SOCKETSTUS sockArr[128];

if (tv.tv_sec - sockArr[i].heartBeatSendTime >= beatTim) 
{ 
   if (send(sockArr[i].sendSockFd, szBuffer, packetSize, 0) != packetSize) 
   { 
     fprintf(stderr, "Heartbeat package send failed：[%d][%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno)); 
     if (errno == EBADF || errno == ECONNRESET || errno == ENOTCONN || errno == EPIPE) 
     { 
       Debug("link lose connection\n"); Reconn(i); continue; 
     } 
   } 
   else 
   { 
     sockArr[i].heartBeatSendTime = tv.tv_sec; 
     if (sockArr[i].status == SOCK_IN_FLY)      
         sockArr[i].heartBeatRecTime = tv.tv_sec; 
   } 
}
```

The error occured in `send()` calls.

Comment: Please add some code, it's the best way to see where things go wrong.

Comment: if (tv.tv_sec - sockArr[i].heartBeatSendTime >= beatTim) {
 if (send(sockArr[i].sendSockFd, szBuffer, packetSize, 0) != packetSize) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Heartbeat package send failed：[%d][%s]\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  if (errno == EBADF || errno == ECONNRESET || errno == ENOTCONN || errno == EPIPE) {
   Debug("link lose connection\n");
   Reconn(i);
   continue;
  }
 }
 else {
  sockArr[i].heartBeatSendTime = tv.tv_sec;
  if (sockArr[i].status == SOCK_IN_FLY)
   sockArr[i].heartBeatRecTime = tv.tv_sec;
 }
}

Comment: the error occured in send() calls

Comment: Sorry I meant in the question (just edit it), the formatting would look better there :)

Comment: Don't put a lot of code in the comments, it doesn't look nice, just edit the original question (click on `edit` just below the tags). anyway, it's been done for you :)

Comment: thank very much, it's in the original question now.

Comment: Please show the definition of "sockArr"

Answer (score 2):

Your error check is incorrect.  `send()` returns the number of bytes sent or -1 on error.  You check only that the return value equals `packetSize`, *not* that the return value indicates error.  [Sometimes `send()` on a stream socket will return fewer bytes than requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618736).

So, some previous syscall (perhaps a harmlessly failed tty manipulation?  a dodgy signal handler?) set `errno` to EIO.

Change your code to treat -1 different from a "short" send.