# Can I call socket send() from different threads?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

If I have a `socket` called `s`, can I do this in different threads:

Thread 1:

```
send(s, "Hello from Thread 1");
```

Thread 2:

```
send(s, "Hello from Thread 2");
```

Is it guaranteed that these two strings will be placed in the send buffer one after the other (I don't care which one is placed first), or is there a possibility that they could get mixed together?

***Note:*** maybe this question should have been titled: "Is socket send() thread safe" (but I am not really sure what thread safety means).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Generally `send()` does not guarantee that the data is being sent in one piece. You always need to check the value returned by `send()` in order to find out how many bytes actually have been sent. If this is less than the size of your buffer (which is *not* an error), you have to call `send()` again, appropriatly in a loop, e.g. something like this:

```
char *msg="Hello from thread 1";
size_t pos;
size_t currentBytes;
size_t BytesToSend=strlen(msg);

for (pos=0 ; pos < BytesToSend ; pos += currentBytes) {
    currentBytes = send(s, msg + pos, BytesToSend - pos, 0);

    if (currentBytes <= 0) {
       // error occurred (-1) or connection has been closed on remote site (0)
       return ...
    }
}
```

That means that you data may arrive in pieces, and when sending from two threads the data may be mixed together.

See also [send()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference, especially

> If no error occurs, send returns the total number of bytes sent, which can be less than the number requested to be sent in the len parameter.

Comment: I thought that a blocking `send()` call will not return until of the data were sent!

Comment: @Tom a blocking send() will not return until at least some bytes were sent.  There's no guarantee it will block until all bytes were sent.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618736/why-is-it-assumed-that-send-may-return-with-less-than-requested-data-transmitted

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner How about `WSASend()`, could it only send part of the data? (`WSASend()` in blocking mode and not using Overlapped I/O).

Comment: I haven't used WSASend() much, so I can only suggest reading its documentation page:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx  (particularly the Remarks section)

Comment: In blocking mode,  `send() ` blocks until all the data had been sent or an error occurs. This is guaranteed by Posix.

Comment: @EJP So the quoted text that sb9 has showed from the `send()` documentation is probably talking about non-blocking sockets? Also is Winsock API compliant with POSIX?

Comment: The quoted text is from the return value section, and in this part the doc doesn't mention blocking or nonblocking. If considering the complete document, it seems that send in a blocking socket won't return before the whole buffer has been sent. The original question did not mention blocking/nonblocking, and when sending I assumed nonblocking. Nevertheless I would not use the same blocking socket from 2 different threads, because oft possible synchronization problems/deadlocks.

Comment: @sb9 You are wrong. There is nothing wrong in calling `send()` from different threads. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981372/are-parallel-calls-to-send-recv-on-the-same-socket-valid

Comment: @mahmoud_t1: that's POSIX.  This is Windows.  The rules are different.

Comment: @Harry Johnston So should a `send()` be enclosed in a critical section to disallow the execution of multiple `send()` at the same time by different threads?

Comment: @John: I'm not sure.  Personally I would follow the more restrictive rules (which are usually true for Windows but might not apply in this particular situation) and use a critical section; it might not be necessary, but it won't do any harm other than a marginal loss of performance.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Sorry, I did not understand what you mean by "the more restrictive rules", you mean simply the use of critical section?

Comment: @John: the usual rules for Windows I/O are more restrictive than the Posix socket rules, i.e., they require the use of a critical section.  Since I'm not certain which rules apply, I would take the cautious approach and use a critical section.

Comment: @mahmoud_t1: I did not write that it won't work, I wrote that I wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: @sb9 Actually you were right, there is a problem in `send()`ing from different threads under Windows.